# How to properly set parameters for Start

Tags: batch-file, cmd

We have frequent computer-lab classes where we need to submit assignments over a local network. We have to submit assignments before the class finishes. The problem is, the destination IP accepts only about 15 maximum connections at a time. Some students like to lobby that for some reason  i.e. they keep their conection open and do not allow others to connect.
To combat this problem I use a simple batch file as follows:

```
:1
start/wait \\10.0.120.5\Shared_\Assignments\
goto 1
```

Although it is rudimentary, it works pretty well for my purposes as it connects to an open spot as soon as it is available. But there are **some problems**:

1. **If the connection is full, its displays "This computer has reached maximum number of connection"** and displays a dialog box. Start/wait being start/wait, naturally waits it out. I'd like for it to skip this and not show me a dialog box if possible.
2. **Right now, If I'm connected, I need to kill the task with taskmanager.** I would like this step to be automatic too. Can I have it so that the batch terminates as soon as the connection is made? Previously, I used an anchor-file(a file I put myself in the teacher's IP in a different folder) to check whether or not it was present to have the batch process know that the connection has been made. This is no longer possible as the server has changed to accept only files in certain locations where uploading such anchor-file is not an option. Surely, there must be a more elegant solution to this.

***My core question is:*** Is it possible to utilize all the parameters provided by Start to achieve this? Or do I need a plethora of conditionals?

Comment: "the destination IP accepts only about 15 maximum connections at a time": I would ask the admin for the server to increase the limit.

Comment: What OS is on the destination computer?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart, its just an individual teacher's personal workdesk computer. I don't think they'll get a dedicated server for each teacher. As it is, the computer is running Windows 10 Professional and 15 seems to be about the limit for local connections to be made at once. Again, I don't think they'll go through the trouble. This has been pointed out before and nothing has been done since. So without any further ado, I'm looking for a solution at my end. And as I mentioned, I did use conditionals to target specific files before. Couldn't do it with folders for some reason.

Comment: The actual connection limit is 20.

Comment: They should be using a server if there are more students that need to connect than a workstation computer can support.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart: There are 220 computers across 4 labs. 96 students are always using one lab or the other so about 2 labs are always occupied. Connectivity is an issue but I believe the college is underfunded to deal with meager issues like this. Nevertheless, I'm expecting a solution at my end. I've found [a way to increase connections](https://scottiestech.info/2009/08/22/how-to-increase-the-10-connection-limit-on-a-windows-lan/) by editing the registry but its a tedious process that has to be repeated on all connecting computers so thats out of the question. Anyways, thanks for tying to help

Comment: You're expecting a solution? I'd suggest adjusting your expectations.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart : It is possible when I think about it. I just need to find the correct way to implement it. Anyways thanks for everything. I'm expecting nothing from you. Have a good day.

Comment: <shrug> OK, good luck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Here's the pretty obvious solution I was looking for!

Tried in the next Lab Class and it turns out I didn't need to target anchor files after all (Ref: 2<sup>nd</sup> part of *Some Problems* [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42405878/5040900)). Sometimes the simple solutions are right there staring back at you.

```
:1
start/wait \\10.0.120.5\Shared_\
if not exist "\\10.0.120.5\Shared_\" goto 1
exit
```

Comment: Of course, now everyone can do this, and you're right back where you started...

Comment: I started with not being able to connect with the folder over IP. Now it works reliably and simply. I never asked for a complicated solution.

Comment: Simplicity isn't the point. I am pointing out that if everyone starts doing this, you are right back where you started.